# Flash CS6 embeded font not visible

Tags: fonts, flash-cs5, flash-cs6

If anyone having same problem.

I have saved my flash CS5 file to new version CS6 and now the embeded fonts are not showing even in IDE I am selecting the non embed version of that font. Even then they are appearing as invisible selectable area, I opened my notepad and selected the font and they are working fine in it.

I tried to save it back in the old version and still having the same problem.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this topic http://forums.adobe.com/message/4916465#4916465

I confirm that rolling back KB2753842 fixes the issue (Windows wants to apply it again so it has to be "hidden"). It's a Critical fix for possible remote code execution due to malicious webfont (scary stuff - you visit a site and get infected), so I hope that either MS or Adobe will remedy the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have a simular problem.  I've been maintaining a Flash object for a few years that reads it's data from an XML file.  The XML file provides the image, link and caption text.  The image is there, the link is there, but the text is GONE!  I can see that space is alocated for the text, but the text just simply is not there.  DID SOMETHING CHANGE IN THE LATEST FLASH/AIR update?