# Flash CS6 embed font not visible

Tags: flash, fonts, embed

I have almost the same problem like here [Flash CS6 embeded font not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909140/flash-cs6-embeded-font-not-visible) but am trying to embed Arial (like millions of times before) and when I publish the movie the font is not appearing. In the C:\Windows\Fonts the Arial font family appears like double (see screenshot) http://tinypic.com/r/2lv1l6p/6 and I think the Flash can't get the file into the swf because of this. I delete the C:\Windows\System32\FNTCACHE.DAT the problem still remains. Well, when I try to delete the one of the duplicate shortcuts, it removes both of them, re-install the font family and again the same... any ideas? I also used those solutions http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1100138 but with no luck. My system is Win7 64-bit with all the latest updates.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "latest updates" is [likely your problem](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4926573#4926573) (even though I haven't had or heard of problems with "plain Jane" fonts like Arial). You need to roll back MS12-078.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I try what you said, didn't work :( The Arial still have double shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

remove the last Windows security update KB2753842 After this, everthing is fine.